# How to correctly compress and convert TiledMap data using Java?

Tags: java, xml, gzip, base64, slick2d

So I'm currently creating a library extension to the [Slick2d](http://slick.cokeandcode.com/) library called [TiledMapPlus](http://slick.javaunlimited.net/viewtopic.php?p=22722). It aims to provide greater support to the people using Tiled, and faster access to data etc.

One of the aims of the library was to provide dynamic map editing, therefore the ability to write a new map to a stream. 
 I implemented this today and yesterday and now need your help. There is something wrong with my code.

So the basic problem is, the XML layer data is **malformed**, and **cannot be read** by the TiledMap parser/editor. 
 I have gone through numerous tutorials trying to compress the data into a **GZIP compressed, BASE64 format**. I have finally resorted to using [this](http://iharder.sourceforge.net/current/java/base64/) with the GZIP compress option. 
 However every time I compress the data etc. It always outputs larger than the Tiled2d editor does and it outputs corrupt data. Why is this?

**Links to Files:**

[A Tiled Map automatically generated by the TiledMap editor](https://raw.github.com/gist/1305988/31b7d10adc05c76aa98abd9cd9008a88cd019c4b/TiledMapOriginal.xml)

[A Tiled Map generated from the above TiledMap, using my library](https://raw.github.com/gist/1305988/38b3047a1ac77223af97983d1318718f63346f86/TiledMapAutoGenerated)

[Snippet of the code from my library which isn't working](https://raw.github.com/gist/1305988/3b3337037e0d20daa02d4df96a300b189ec9565f/TiledMapPlusSnippet.java)

[Alternatively you can view them all formatted here](https://gist.github.com/1305988)

Comment: Couldn't follow all of that but I know that using base64 for something you want to compress is a pretty *bad* idea.  But then again, any decent compressor will pick up on the fact that every 7th and 8th bit in a byte is always 0 and compress accordingly...

Comment: If its any confusion, I'm compressing the data using GZIP, then converting it into Base64. Its the TiledMap standard, I didn't define it lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Liam I've actually been following every possible thing I can find that you've written and it was your code in TiledMapPlus that finally solved this for me.

Here is the solution that works correctly taken from Liam's code:

```
            Element layer = doc.createElement("layer");
        layer.setAttribute("name", "layer");
        layer.setAttribute("width", width);
        layer.setAttribute("height", height);



            Element data = doc.createElement("data");

            ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();                
            for(int tileY = 0;tileY<layerHeight;tileY++){
                for(int tileX = 0;tileX<layerWidth;tileX++){
                    int tileGID = this.data[tileX][tileY];
                    os.write(tileGID);
                    os.write(tileGID << 8);
                    os.write(tileGID << 16);
                    os.write(tileGID << 24);
                }
            }
            os.flush();
            String compressedData = Base64.encodeBytes(os.toByteArray(),Base64.DONT_BREAK_LINES|Base64.GZIP|Base64.ENCODE);
            data.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(compressedData));               
            data.setAttribute("encoding", "base64");
            data.setAttribute("compression","gzip");

            layer.appendChild(data);

        mapElement.appendChild(layer);
```

I am using my same data generation techniques and passing in any id number I want and it is accepting and encoding it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using is setting up a pipeline of output streams like this:

ObjectOutputStream -> GZIPOutputStream -> Base64OutputStream

You will not want to have the first ObjectOuputStream, since it is serializing a JAVA byte array object. You should just feed the GZIpOuputStream with the bytes directly. If you cannot find a suitable method, it is very easy to set up your own using apache commons codec:

```
public String compressAndEncode(byte[] data) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gz = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
    int c;
    while ((c = in.read()) != -1)
        gz.write(c);
    gz.finish();
    Base64 b = new Base64(0);
    return b.encodeToString(out.toByteArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant speak to the value of the answer from forty-two.  If it worked please respond saying so.   I have gotten this working in a game Im writing and the problem is in the format you're using.

When you create a TMX file that has the data compressed and gziped as is required for TiledMapPlus and slick2d you DONT use the `<tiled>` tags like the general non-compressed files.  Its counter intuitive but thats how it works.

To create the data in the `<data>` tag you need to create a string/stream of each gid using a 32bit integer and then convert it to UTF-8 and then compress and encode it.

Here is an example that I found somewhere on the web:

```
                Element data = doc.createElement("data");
            data.setAttribute("encoding", "base64");
            data.setAttribute("compression", "gzip");

                String bytestring = new String();
                for (int x = 0; x < w; x++) {                       
                    for (int y = 0; y < h; y++) {
                        switch(this.data[x][y]){

                            case 0: bytestring += "1000";
                                break;
                            case 1: bytestring += "2000";
                                break;
                            case 2: bytestring += "3000";
                                break;
                            case 3: bytestring += "4000";
                                break;
                            case 4: bytestring += "5000";
                                break;
                            case 5: bytestring += "6000";
                                break;
                            case 6: bytestring += "7000";
                                break;
                            case 7: bytestring += "8000";
                                break;
                            case 8: bytestring += "9000";
                                break;

                        }
                    }
                }

                Text value = doc.createTextNode(compress(bytestring));
                data.appendChild(value);
```

The compression and encoding are done like this:

```
private static String compress(String str){

    byte byteAry[] = null;

    try{
        byteAry = str.getBytes("UTF-8");    
    }catch( UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        System.out.println("Unsupported character set");
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < byteAry.length; i++) {
        if(byteAry[i] == 48)
            byteAry[i] = 0;
        if(byteAry[i] == 49)
            byteAry[i] = 1;
        if(byteAry[i] == 50)
            byteAry[i] = 2;
        if(byteAry[i] == 51)
            byteAry[i] = 3;
        if(byteAry[i] == 52)
            byteAry[i] = 4;
        if(byteAry[i] == 53)
            byteAry[i] = 5;
        if(byteAry[i] == 54)
            byteAry[i] = 6;
        if(byteAry[i] == 55)
            byteAry[i] = 7;
        if(byteAry[i] == 56)
            byteAry[i] = 8;
        if(byteAry[i] == 57)
            byteAry[i] = 9;
    }
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    try {
        OutputStream deflater = new GZIPOutputStream(buffer);
        deflater.write(byteAry);
        deflater.close();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
    String results = Base64.encodeBase64String(buffer.toByteArray());
    return results;
}
```

Now here is a more advanced question that is highly related.  In the above example you can see each GID is being represented by a 32bit string such as 1000.  These associate directly with the included tileset file.  I am having a problem in that I can seem to use this technique to go above GID 9 (show as 9000).  I believe this is something to do with the ByteStream itself.  If I enter 1100 it crashes as a null value for the GID of that tile (when reading the file in) even though the tileset has 20 or so tiles in it.  So there is something wrong w/ what gets returned after the encoding and compression for any 2 digit number.  This seems rather java specific as the people doing obj-c work with this dont seem to hit this same problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As of note, I am the creator of TiledMapPlus library, which can write TiledMap files.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion but this article comes up when looking into randomly generated maps.  As this is everywhere hopefully my additions will help people with that.  My 'advanced' problem is solved in my other post.   Basically there is a better way then this string technique I found.  The better way is the way Liam does it in the write() method of TiledMapPlus found [here](https://github.com/liamzebedee/TiledMapPlus/blob/master/src/org/newdawn/slick/tiled/TiledMapPlus.java).

Thanks again for your spectacular work on this library Liam.

BTW any word on passing data between states?

Comment: Was I correct in assuming forty-two's answer didnt really solve the problem?  It was the fact you were encoding the '<tiled>' tags, right?

This comes up for a lot of map generation issues out there so I added some detail b/c a lot of people seem to be having trouble with  random maps etc.  Maybe this will help others.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that was the issue. Um data being passed from states, as far as I know, not really. I solve the problem using singletons, but that's just me.